# Gulp Watch is just for online time process? i mean for watch changes i need to continue open the ssh window?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I want to know gulp watch is just for on time when using SSH window? I mean if the SSH window is open then html and CSS on changes it is working and when I close the SSH window then it is not working. We can run the gulp watch forever? I mean without SSH and apply the changes every time?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen program for linux is exactly what you are looking for:
Install screen
Open a new screen session: screen -dR
Start gulp
Disconnect from your screen session: CTRL-A, d
Run a command in a shell and keep running the command when you close the session.
its solved my problem.